# convert date kendo ui grid

Tags: php, date, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have Kendo UI grid when I save a new date value,  the value send as POST request like

> Wed Jun 19 2013 17:48:32 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)

I am trying to take this value and send to the web service which waiting value with type "DateTime"

I want to convert the sending value date even in Kendo UI before send as POST value or

in the PHP file when I receive this value

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kendo ui allow set culture and date format adding

please checkout http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#culture

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting

Reading i found this:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/globalization/kendo-fails-to-parse-or-format-utc-dates.aspx

```
    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                            if (operation != "read") {
                                var d = new Date(options.Date);
                                options.Date = d.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");                            
                                return options;
                            }
                        }
{ field: "Date", title: "Date ", type: "date", format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" }

result : 30/08/2012
```

Comment: I set the culture and I can change the date format in displaying the grid, but the value still sent as the previous format. Any way to format it from php

Comment: how are you sending data ?

Comment: Using the data-source, I specify a php URL in the create. I set the type as POST

Comment: I am using similar code, the date is displayed formatted correctly. but it sent in a different format

Comment: Kamal, I am facing the same issue. Did you get the solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

kamal , I think this would be the solution and this how I solve it

```
   parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation != "read") {
     //change the fieldDate variable to your field date 
    var d = new Date(options.models[0].fieldDate);
    options.models[0].fieldDate = kendo.toString(new Date(d), "yyyy-MM-dd");                            
                            return options;
                        }
                    }
```

it might help someone like me ...